# Codeigniter. Validate PUT data

Tags: codeigniter, validation

I am developing an API using Phils RestServer and I need to validate incoming PUT data. It works fine with
incoming POST data but not PUT.

How can I validate data that are sent via PUT?

Thankful for all input!

Comment: Take a look here: http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.put-method.php
The example 1 shows a way to read in the PUT data, so just get rid of the file writing and validate as you would any other file.

Comment: Mm, I am using Codeigniter and it has a build in validation system. It works fine with POST requests but not with PUT. How can I get it to work with PUT?

Comment: Unfortunately I think that'd be a fairly advanced modification to CodeIgniter. You'd likely be better off validating on a case by case basis. This ie especially true since you're probably got (a) specific controller(s) to handle PUT requests.

Comment: In version 3 you can apply form validation to any array, not just $_POST. Like so: 

$this->form_validation->set_data($data); // Where $data would be the data you obtained via PUT.

Docs here: https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/form_validation.html#validating-an-array-other-than-post

Answer (score 5):

Nope! Doesn't work. What you CAN do is hack it, so:

```
$_POST['foo'] = $this->put('foo');
```

Allowing the CodeIgniter Form Validation class to validate things other than POST is on the todo list (for exactly this reason).

Comment: In your controller before you run()

Comment: I am sorry to ask but where exactly. In the constructor or in the function?

Comment: There is also a problem with the DELETE. Shouldn´t I be able to do method.json?foo=bar and be able to access foo with $this->delete('foo');? I does not work. Only if I send it in the body of the request. This does not work either $this->get('foo');

Comment: Clearly, as DELETE is not POST. In a perfect "spec following world" delete would not be sending parameters anyway, simply calling a URL to delete.

Answer (score 3):

Here is my solution. I am using set_data() function from form validation library:

```
$set_data = array(
        'username'  => $this->put('username'),
        'email'     => $this->put('email'),
        'zipcode'   => $this->put('zipcode'),
        'telephone' => $this->put('telephone'),
        'password'  => $this->put('password'),
    );

    $this->form_validation->set_data($set_data);
    $this->form_validation->set_rules($this->Register_model->rules_register);
```

Answer (score 2):

It's working fine by using set_data(). Say 'MRP' and 'IsActive' parameters are sent by put request.

```
$this->form_validation->set_data($this->put());

$this->form_validation->set_rules('MRP', 'MRP', 'numeric|greater_than[0]|less_than[10000]', array());
$this->form_validation->set_rules('IsActive', 'Is Active', 'required|alpha|min_length[2]|max_length[2]', array());

if ($this->form_validation->run() === TRUE) {
    // Do Stuff..
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I realized after my first answer this all depends on what version of CI you are using, if your using the latest 3.0.0 or later, then you can make 1 small adjustment in the form validation file.

Form_validation.php file at the top of the set_rules() method on line 176

FROM :

```
if ($this->CI->input->method() !== 'post' && empty($this->validation_data)) {
    return $this;
}
```

TO:

```
if ($this->CI->input->method() !== 'post' && $this->CI->input->method() !== 'put' && empty($this->validation_data)) {
    return $this;
}
```

Let me know if this helped.